Moon's ecliptic latitude and longitude
Is there a way to compute the Moon's ecliptic latitude and longitude without declination or right ascension?
Note: I have a formula to compute the Moon's position that uses an ecliptic latitude and longitude to compute declination or right ascension so that's why I can't use them to compute ecliptic latitude and longitude.

As mentioned in the comments on your earlier question, there isn't a simple way to calculate the Moon's position with high accuracy. The Moon's orbit is complicated! See here for other complicated lunar patterns.

Please don't use so much bolding. It makes the text hard to read.

We need to know this information.  A) How accurate do you want the position?  B) what time frame is acceptable?  For example,  the Astronomical Almanac gives equations for each year, to within X fraction of a degree.

Generally, using declination and right ascension to calculate ecliptic latitude and longitude is a good idea, but if you want to see a potential way to do it without using them, consider this:
Consider a geocentric frame where the observer is in the center of the Earth, the moon is orbiting around the Earth in a circular orbit with a radius of $3.84\times10^8 m$. (this is a highly simplified model and does not really match the reality)
The moon revolves around the Earth in a orbit with inclination, $i = 5.14^{\circ}$, the orbit of Moon will trace a great circle on the celestial sphere (now call it lunar great circle), with a angle of $i' = 5.14^{\circ}$ to the orbit of Sun (ecliptic). Thus the two great circle have two point where they meet.
Now we establish a coordinate system with lunar great circle as its great circle, it is just like any other spherical coordinate system. For simplicity, define lunar longitude as the angular separation between the ascending node and the projection of the object on the lunar great circle. (basically equatorial system but changing the great circle and ascending node)
Since the Moon is always on lunar great circle, its lunar longitude is $0^{\circ}$, the Moon orbit around Earth in a circular orbit, the motion of the Moon on the lunar great circle is a uniform motion. Thus at any given moment, the lunar longitude of the moon is:
$\lambda' = \frac{t}{T_0} \times 360^{\circ}$
Where $t$ is the time after the last time where Moon pass through the ascending node, $T_0$ is the orbital period of the Moon.
Now you can use spherical trigonometry to convert coordinate system, it is the same method you use to obtain an equation of Moon's ecliptic latitude and longitude to get declination and right ascension.
You can make it more accurate by adding $\omega(t)$, this is a function of angular velocity on celestial sphere, and integrate it over time to get the distance Moon travels on the celestial sphere.

How does this simple model help the OP to calculate the Moon's actual position?

@PM 2Ring, Spherical trigonometry, i define a new coordinate system, give the way to compute moon's coordinate, all that is left is to use spherical trigonometry
